# Getting error in my class file - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, jar, sbt

I am getting class not found exception when submitting scala project fat jar to spark cluster.

My spark submit command:

```
 spark-submit  --deploy-mode cluster  \
--master "spark://master-node:7077"  \
--class input  \
--packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.12:3.0.1  \
 /home/jars/sql-mongo-validation.jar
```

Class definition

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrameReader, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

object input {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {...}

  def sqlServerReader(spark: SparkSession){...}
}
```

Build.sbt: https://github.com/shantanugupta/spark-mongo-sqlserver-cluster-mode/blob/main/build.sbt

```
name := "sql-mongo-validation"
version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.12.10"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "3.1.2"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "3.1.2"
libraryDependencies += "com.microsoft.sqlserver" % "mssql-jdbc" % "7.4.1.jre11"
connector
libraryDependencies += "org.mongodb.spark" %% "mongo-spark-connector" % "3.0.1"

Compile / mainClass  := Some("input")
assembly / mainClass := Some("input")

assembly / assemblyMergeStrategy  := {
  case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

**Error**

> :: resolution report :: resolve 205ms :: artifacts dl 6ms     :: modules
> in use:   org.mongodb#bson;4.0.5 from central in [default]
> org.mongodb#mongodb-driver-core;4.0.5 from central in [default]
> org.mongodb#mongodb-driver-sync;4.0.5 from central in [default]
> org.mongodb.spark#mongo-spark-connector_2.12;3.0.1 from central in
> [default]

> :: retrieving ::
> org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent-1799f36e-dbf4-479d-a61f-945264494f41
> confs: [default]    0 artifacts copied, 4 already retrieved (0kB/6ms)
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: input    at
> java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)   at
> java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)     at
> java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)     at
> java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)     at
> java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)     at
> org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:207)    at
> org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverWrapper$.main(DriverWrapper.scala:63)
> at
> org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverWrapper.main(DriverWrapper.scala)
> 21/09/01 21:23:22 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
> 21/09/01 21:23:22 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory
> /tmp/spark-6044c74d-72a5-47d0-a8c9-e58a812abd6f

Comment: Have you tried with the input's package name ? e.g.  --class com.myproject.input (if you have packages in your project) ?

Comment: @ccheneson I don't have any package name. I checked-in my code in git repo link shared above for more details

Comment: Is your sql-mongo-validation.jar in a home directory called "jars" ?

Comment: @ccheneson Yes, it's in the same directory.

Comment: please provide your build.sbt Also i woud recommend to use sbt-assmbly for spark https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly

Comment: @IvaKam Added build.sbt

Comment: @ShantanuGupta in the same directory as ? I am asking this because you have a /home/shangupta directory (in the docker cmd in your build.sbt) and a /home/jars directory.

Comment: @ccheneson  `root@aa86362ea8bd:/opt/spark# ls /home/jars/` list below jar `sql-mongo-validation.jar`